# resource loading algorithm

Tags: algorithm

This is a classic CS problem I encountered in my work:
I have a list of resources  I need to load. each resource has a list of constraints  it needs in order to load and when loaded satisfies other constraints that other resources may need. In example: resource X has a,b,c as constraints so it can only load when a,b and c are fulfilled. when loaded, X satisfies constraints n and m which are needed by resource Y which also needs constraint p in order to load so when another resource will load and satisfy the p constraint, Y will load, and in turn satisfy other constraints. 
The list of constraints needed by all resources  is final, meaning that each resource may need several constraints and each constraint may be needed by several resources. 
Also, one resource needs null constraints in order to load hence must be the first to load.

Ok, after this long explanation here is my question: 
How can I find the best loading sequence of the resources when all I know in advance is which constraints are needed per resource but do not know (in advance) which constraints are satisfied by a resource once loaded?

hope my explanation was clear enough...
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Simple Solution:

Create a Bipartite Graph with n Vertices (resources) and m Vertices (constraints). - **O(n + m)**

Hold the constraints in some lookup table data structure (i.e. a hash table).

Draw edges between resource vertices and constraint vertices whenever a resource needs that constraint.

Create a list **L** of resources, initially empty. (this is the order in which to load the resources).

Create a set **R** of resources, initiallly empty. (this is the set of resources which can be added currently). - **O(1)**

Add the one resource that has 0 constraints to **R**. - **O(1)**

while **R** is not empty:

{

Get some resource **r** from **R** - **O(1)**

Add **r** to **L** - **O(1)**

Let **S** be the set of all constraints that the resource **r** fulfills when being loaded.

Foreach constraint **c** in **S** lookup the constraint vertex and remove all links going to this vertex. If at the other side of the link, there are no more links (meaning that the resource vertex is now ready to be loaded), add that vertex to **R**. - **O(|S|)**

}

TOTAL RUNNING TIME: O(n * |S|), where |S| is the maximum number of constraints fulfilled by a single resource.

Comment: I don't think you need the priority queue; just a list of those resources whose constraints are satisfied should suffice. As links are removed, just check to see if it was the last link to a resource, adding it to the list if so. This gives O(m) run time, where m is the number of links.

Comment: @michael Isn't it O(n*m), because you have to scan all the remaining links every time resource is loaded?

Comment: @blaze and michael - That solution would be O(n*m). However, it is necessary that you always add the resource with 0 missing constraints. And whenever you add a resource, you are getting new information as to which constraints are now fulfilled. So for n resources you have to go through possibly m constraints. Keeping them in a priority queue gives you a maximum efficiency. It will not be possible to get an algorithm below n Log(n).

Comment: By the way: keeping the resources in a priority queue is one way to improve efficiency, the other (which I would suggest to also do) is to keep the constraint vertices in a hashmap. If you can identify a constraint by some hash value this would allow you to delete the edges of the bipartite graph without searching for them!

Comment: @blaze You do not need to scan all remaining links. You need only be able to detect whether it was the last link to the resource; the degree of the resource vertices can be stored with the vertices, if the graph representation doesn't otherwise support that test as O(1). You thus follow m1 links from constraints to resources, and m2 (implicit) links from resources to the constraints they satisfy (left this out before). That gives O(m1+m2), doing everything else exactly as Christian suggested in his answer.

Comment: @Christian Yes, I'm definitely assuming a hash table or other O(1) lookup of the constraints satisfied by the resources. You are as well, I think, when you "go through all constraint vertices that the resource offers" -- if you can do that, why do you need the priority queue?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber I am also assuming some O(1) lookup for the constraints. The priority queue is for the resources. You always want to add the resource with the lowest amount of missing links (missing constraints). That's why I suggested a priority queue containing the resource vertices, sorted by the amount of links per vertex.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber - Oh I think you're right. We do not even need any priority queue. Because there is a well defined starting resource (the one without constraints), you can add that one first, then lookup in O(1) all constraints that are now satisfied. Then delete the aforementioned links to the resources and automatically add a new resource whenever it has 0 links. This way, the algorithm does not need a priority queue (only a bipartite graph and a lookup table) and would run in: O(n * m).

Comment: @Christian Resources can only be added when the constraints are satisfied, so the number of missing constraints must always be zero - you could just wait until the number of unsatisfied constraints hits zero to enqueue the resource, and sorting is never needed. If there were, say, a cost for loading a resource proportional to the number of unsatisfied constraints, then the priority queue would be a good approach, with O(m1 + m2 + n*log(n)) time (m1 and m2 as in the earlier comment).

Comment: @Christian Cool. You've already got my upvote, though, as the bipartite graph is the key point.

Comment: thank you. I agree, this is actually correct and works perfectly!

Comment: I guess I'll pull my comments together into an answer as well, to save some trouble for anyone reading the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

An easy algorithm, with poor complexity ( O(n^2 * m) where n is number of resources and m is number of constraints for resource):

```
Set resourcesToLoad = ...
List loadingOrder = new List()
Set constraintsSatisfied = new Set()
while (!resourcesToLoad.empty) {
    for (resource in resourcesToLoad) {
        if (constraintsSatisfied.containsAll(resource.constraintsNeeded) {
            resourcesToLoad.remove(resource);
            loadingOrder.arr(resource);
            constraintsSatisfied.addAll(resource.constraintsProvided)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If each resource loaded in constant time Ta, Tb, Tc and this time is long enough compared to order calculations, your list of resources will be loaded in time sum(Ta, Tb, Tc) in any loading order.

If order calculation time is significant, you task is "quickly find element without unsatisfied constraints". Best algorithm I can think of now is still O(N^2), no better then "scan list until find matching element".

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Christian, the relations between the resources and constraints define a bipartite graph. A simple way to work with that graph is to represent it as a mapping (e.g., a hash table) from the constraints to those resources that require the constraint. Additionally, keep a mapping from the resources to the number of unsatisfied constraints and a list of those resources for which all constraints are satisfied.

If we assume the initial relations are given by a mapping from resources to lists of constraints, the solution should look something like this:

```
# resource_constraints must be given as a mapping 
#   from resource to list of needed constraints

loaded_resources = [] # list of resources already loaded
pending_resources = [] # list of resources we can load, but haven't yet
constraint_resources = {} # mapping from constraints to resources needing them
number_unsatisfied = {} # mapping from resources to number of unsatisfied constraints

for r in resource_constraints:
    constraints = resource_constraints[r]
    if not constraints:
        pending_resources.append(r)
    else:
        number_unsatisfied[r] = len(constraints)
        for c in constraints:
            if c not in constraint_resources:
                constraint_resources[c] = []
            constraint_resources[c].append[r]

assert len(pending_resources) > 0, "Must be at least one unconstrained resource"

while pending_resources:
    r1 = pending_resources.pop()
    loaded_resources.append(r1)
    for c in resource_constraints[r1]:
        if c in constraint_resources:
            for r2 in constraint_resources[c]:
                number_unsatisfied[r2] -= 1
                if number_unsatisfied[r2] == 0:
                    del number_unsatisfied[r2]
                    pending_resources.append(r2)
            del constraint_resources[c]

assert len(loaded_resources) == len(resource_constraints), "Must load all resources"
```

The above is Python, written to use only simple features to act as a pseudocode.

With this approach, the total running time is O(m1 + m2), where m1 is the sum of the number of constraints required by the resources and m2 is the sum of the number of constraints provided by the resources; m1 can be determined in advance, but m2 is unknown until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Build a tree representing the dependencies and load the resources as returned by a depth-first walk through the tree (reversed).

Check out [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Depth-first-tree.svg) from wikipedia... the order in which you should be loading the resources is 12, 11, 10 and so on... There are of course alternatives.

Comment: Does not fully work, because it is not known what the root should be. A topological ordering is needed here. Also a constraint may be present twice, son normal DFS this resource would be loaded twice.

Comment: @LiKao is finding a tree root really an issue?

Comment: Yes: look at this graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Directed_acyclic_graph.png. It is not clear what the root should be.

Comment: @LiKao you're right, I missed the case where the top-level can contain multiple resources.